# How to solve the serve static content from a cookieless domain in prestashop 1.5?

Tags: performance, prestashop, yslow

I test my website on gtmetrix.com it show me the following error to improve my website yslow scrore.

**serve static content from a cookieless domain**

how to solve this error?

Comment: what is you website please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create some subdomains for example: `media1.example.com`, `media2.example.com`, `media3.example.com`.

Configure those subdomains to point to your website as your main domain does.

In Prestashop backoffice go to `Performances` and register your new content domains in the `media` area.

Those domains will only be used to serve static content and will never be assigned cookies.

Comment: i have create subdomain like test.example.com and img folder is move example.com to test.example.com but images does not shown.