# How to make the cookie less sub domain?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, subdomain, prestashop

I test my website on gtmetrix.com it show me the following error to improve my website yslow scrore.

**serve static content from a cookieless domain**

how to solve this error?

Comment: You need to learn about cookies and HTTP requests. Whether this is even possible on your site depends on your current implementation (ie. are you serving content from the www subdomain or the apex domain? What domain/host is currently being used when cookies are set?)

Comment: i already create subdomain of website and move all static content main domain to subdomain folder @user82217

Comment: use media server and remove all static cookie less content to media server.

Comment: In Media Servers settings. In the first field enter  static sub domain URL like static.example.com and save the settings. but still now create the same issue @MdKamruzzaman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the serve static content from a cookieless domain in prestashop 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045532/how-to-solve-the-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain-in-prestashop-1-5)